# Jinja2 comprobar si un valor existe en una lista de diccionarios

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, template

Estoy tratando de comprobar si un valor existe dentro de una lista con diccionario. Uso flask 1.0.2. Miren el ejemplo a continuación:

```
person_list_dict = [
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@mydomain.com",
        "rol": "admin"
    },
    {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "email": "johnsmith@mydomain.com",
        "rol": "user"
    }
]
```

Encontré dos forma de resolver el problema, ¿pueden decirme cuál es mejor?:

## Primera opción: jinja2 built-in template filter "map"

```
<pre>{% if "admin" in person_list_dict|map(attribute="rol") %}SI{% else %}NO{% endif %}</pre>
# return SI (john doe) and NO (john smith)
```

## Segunda opción: Flask template filter

Código flask:

```
@app.template_filter("is_in_list_dict")
def is_any(search="", list_dict=None, dict_key=""):
    if any(search in element[dict_key] for element in list_dict):
        return True
    return False
```

código plantilla:

```
<pre>{% if "admin"|is_in_list_dict(person_list_dict, "rol") %} SI {% else %} NO {% endif %}</pre>
# return SI (john doe) and NO (john smith)
```

Gracias :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque podría considerarse una cuestión de opinión, creo que hay razones objetivas para preferir el primer enfoque. Serían las siguientes:

1. **Menos código**. Al estar usando filtros pre-existentes de jinja2, no necesitas añadir código extra en tu aplicación Flask. Menos cosas que mantener y testear.
2. **Código más legible**. Aunque la parte de `map(attribute="rol")` requiere conocer qué hace exactamente esta función en jinja2, no resulta difícil imaginar qué será. Una vez se comprende que se han extraido todos los campos "rol" de la lista de diccionarios, es obvio que basta con buscar si la cadena "admin" está entre ellos. A cambio la versión Flask requiere comprender qué es un decorador `template_filter`, comprender que la *list comprehension* que aparece en la función produce una lista de booleanos, y conocer la función `any()`. Además, una vez creado ese filtro en Flask, su uso dentro del template resulta también anti-intuitivo, puesto que no se está usando realmente para filtrar una lista (esto es, seleccionar elementos de la misma), sino más bien como una condición para el if.
3. **Eficiencia**. Aún sin saber cómo Jinja2 implementa en realidad el filtro `map`, podemos suponer que en el fondo estará haciendo una *list comprehension* que dará como resultado la lista de cadenas encontradas en el campo "rol". El tiempo requerido para crear esa lista será proporcional al número de elementos en la misma. Una vez se tiene, el operador `cadena in lista` se traducirá al mismo operador `in` en Python, el cual es muy eficiente. La segunda versión también necesita recorrer la lista de diccionarios completa, para crear una lista de booleanos, y después `any()` necesita revisar si hay en ella algún `True` (lo cual también es muy eficiente, pues no revisa la lista entera y se detiene en el primer `True` que encuentre). Aún así, la segunda versión requiere más operaciones al crear la lista de booleanos, ya que por cada elemento de la lista original debe comparar su "rol" con el buscado, y eso lo hace para todos los elementos de la lista (cuando podría haberse detenido al encontrar el primero).

   Puede parecer que la diferencia sería despreciable, pero he hecho algunas medidas y, para una lista con sólo dos elementos, la primera opción tarda 631ns y la segunda 833ns. Diferencias de nanosegundos son obviamente irrelevantes, pero si la lista fuese mucho más larga podrían ser ya importantes, pues la segunda opción tarda como un 25% más que la primera.

   No sólo el tiempo de procesamiento de la segunda opción es ligeramente mayor, sino que además añade un nivel extra de indirección en su ejecución, ya que el *renderizador* del template Jinja debe invocar a la función python que actúa como filtro. No obstante la invocación se realiza una sola vez y el tiempo consumido aquí no depende del tamaño de la lista.
4. **Robustez**. Si intentas mirar un campo que no exista en los diccionarios (por ejemplo, cambias `"rol"` por `"role"`, la primera opción seguirá funcionando, y dará como resultado `<pre>NO</pre>`, que es razonable. La segunda opción producirá una excepción en la función python al tratar de acceder a `element[dict_key]`.

Comment: Era más o menos lo que pensaba y tu respuesta me ha terminado de convencer. Gracias @abulafia